# Send an image to yolo (darknet) and receive object position and type

Tags: c#, pinvoke, yolo

Is there a possibility to send an image from C# to [yolo](https://github.com/pjreddie/darknet) and receive all detected object positions and types.

For example on the demo image

```
type      | x   | y   | width | height
-------------------------------------------
bicycle   | 214 | 150 | 450   | 378
dog       | 150 | 260 | 210   | 350
truck     | 540 | 100 | 250   | 150
```

[image: yolo detection result]

**Example code**

```
public class Yolo
{
    public ObjectPosition[] GetObjects(Image image)
    {
        //return yolo result
    }
}

public class ObjectPosition
{
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public int X { get; set; }
    public int Y { get; set; }
    public int Width { get; set; }
    public int Height { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can use this nuget package [Alturos.Yolo](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Alturos.Yolo) for your requirement. More informations you found on the [product page](https://github.com/AlturosDestinations/Alturos.Yolo).

**Install dependency**

First install this two nuget packages, the first one is the logic with opencv and the c++ yolo project, the second one contains the yolo config data.

```
PM> install-package Alturos.Yolo
PM> install-package Alturos.YoloV2TinyVocData
```

**Code example**

```
using (var yoloWrapper = new YoloWrapper("yolov2-tiny-voc.cfg", "yolov2-tiny-voc.weights", "voc.names"))
{
    var items = yoloWrapper.Detect("image.jpg");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

YOLO doesn't appear to expose an endpoint for retrieving the results AND the bounding boxes.

If you read through the YOLO webpage, you'll see that instead, at the command line it will return strings with objects and confidence ratings, and the bounding boxes (as seen in the demo predictions image) are actually **output to a predictions.png file.**

I believe if you want those bounding boxes, you'll likely need to download the YOLO source code and tweak its console output to return those values as well.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using https://github.com/AlexeyAB/darknet fork to use yolo on windows. There are yolo_cpp_dll and yolo_cpp_dll_no_gpu projects there to build Yolo DLL. It's "detect" function gets image and returns set of detections, each is struct: {x,y,w,h,prob,class_id}. There is also darknet.py example of using this DLL from python. I don't thing it will be more difficult from c#.

Comment: Have you an example for C#?

Comment: No, I use C++ .

Comment: Hey In my case I am using OpenCV or OpenCVSharp now I wanted a facial recognition opencv can detect faces using haar cascade classifier and the margin error is quite huge. Someone suggested to me to use deep learning and I wanted yolo for recognition and opencv for detection